# What is changing the startup font in grub console mode?

Tags: command-line, grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and boot the system with GRUB_TERMINAL="console". During startup, I see the messages rush by, then something turns off colors (all green OK's turn white), then the font becomes thinner, colors resume, the font then becomes slightly thicker, before I see the prompt.

I would love to have the initial typeset/font, same as presented by the grub menu. I already tried to mask systemd console-setup.service (including several other systemd services) at the kernel command line, but the issue persists. Perhaps it isn't a font issue, but something initializing the screen?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The culprit is console-setup.service. Here's how I fixed the issue.

> Edit /etc/default/console-setup
> -> FONTFACE="VGA"
> -> FONTSIZE="8x16"

You can also set it to "", but I found VGA easier to read - not as bold.

You will also have to update your initrd.img for the change to take affect, otherwise there would be a systemd console-setup startup error, complaining about some missing file in /tmp. Also be sure to use -u and not -c with the following command.

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Alternatively, you can also disable the systemd service using the following grub kernel command line, which presumable uses whatever you have configured as the default in the kernel.

> systemd.mask=console-setup.service

I guess that's pretty much it in a nutshell. I don't see why I would want anything else but plain English and fancy font for my console, but that's probably a different question. The system installation default to me was not acceptable.

I almost forgot to mention that you can also use:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

...and follow the screens. It will show you available options and also update initramfs, but apparently only the latest version it finds installed, which is perhaps a bug.